# How start new activity with click on table rows and pass data to new activity in EditText

Tags: android

Following is my code and I have already set OnClickListener with each table row,it is working. Now I want to start a new activity when user click on any row and also I want to pass the data of row to new activity in a textedit.

```
            Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student WHERE rollno='"+docno.getText()+"'", null);

                  int rows = c.getCount();
                  table_layout.removeAllViews();
                  c.moveToFirst();
                  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

                      String rollno  = c.getString(0);
                      String name    = c.getString(1);
                      String marks   = c.getString(2);
                   TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
                   row.setClickable(true); 
                    row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                        }
                    });

                   row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                    TextView et = new TextView(this);
                    TextView name1 = new TextView(this);
                    TextView marks1 = new TextView(this);

                    name1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                    et.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    et.setTextSize(10);
                    et.setText(rollno);

                    name1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    name1.setTextSize(10);
                    name1.setText(name);
                    name1.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
                    name1.setHeight(20);
                    name1.setWidth(180);

                    marks1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    marks1.setTextSize(10);
                    marks1.setText(marks);

                    row.addView(et);
                    row.addView(name1);
                    row.addView(marks1);

                   table_layout.addView(row);
                   c.moveToNext();

                  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, a few are described below.

You can use the putExtra method for your new intent.  You can either do this by passing the data as text or you can expose the Cursor and simply pass the row number.  To pass the data as text, in your onClick:

```
Intent intt = new Intent(this,NewActivity.class);
intt.putExtra("rollno",rollno);
intt.putExtra("name",name);
intt.putExtra("marks",marks);
startActivity(intt);
```

Then in your NewActivity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null) {
    // Use extras.getString("rollno") in your setText method in your new activity
    // Use extras.getString("name") in your setText method in your new activity
    // Use extras.getString("marks") in your setText method in your new activity
}
```

You could also expose your Cursor by declaring it inside your class, but outside/before your onCreate method.

```
public static Cursor c;
```

Then in your onCreate remove the 'Cursor' keyword at the start.  You can then pass the data in as a row number in your onClick as such:

```
Intent intt = new Intent(this,NewActivity.class);
intt.putExtra("rownum",i);
startActivity(intt);
```

Then in your new activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int rownum;
if(extras != null) {
    c.moveToPosition(extras.getInt("rownum"));
    et.setText(MainActivity.c.getString(0));
    name1.setText(MainActivity.c.getString(1));
    marks1.setText(MainActivity.c.getString(2));
}
```

You could even simply skip passing the data through the intent, in the onClick:

```
c.moveToPosition(i);
Intent intt = new Intent(this,NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intt);
```

Then when you reference MainActivity.c (your cursor object) using getString() in your NewActivity, the correct row will have already been set for you.  However, this requires that you always call moveToPosition

Id also like to suggest a few other tips.  You should use a different naming convention for your layout objects.  Using variables such as name, name1, marks, marks1 will lead to confusion.  Instead use name, nameText or marksString, marksTextView.

Also for your db query, you should use query() method.  Instead of:

```
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student WHERE rollno='"+docno.getText()+"'", null);
```

Use:

```
c=db.query("student","rollno="+docno.getText.toString(),null,null,null,null,null);
```

This also assumes you have declared 'c' as a Cursor already as explained above.  You also cannot guarantee that your columns will be exactly where you expect them to be, so instead of using

```
c.getString(0)
```

to retrieve column 0, instead you should instead use:

```
c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("columnName");
```

Where 'columnName' is the name of the column in the table.

Comment: you advice me about two method to pass the data with putExtra ,data as text or expose the Cursor, which is the best method forever actually I am new in android.

Comment: This depends entirely on what your end goal is. Ideally your new activity shouldn't be handling the Cursor directly from your main activity. You also may want to start with empty values or a different Cursor, so pass your Strings in the bundle. When you get more complex records you may look at creating a Class for each record and referencing it by Class. (Imagine a C-style struct that implements its own private methods).

Comment: Dear Dvaey, I also want to disappear selected row, but if data successfully enter to database. can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Particularly the "Start the second activity" section seems to be precisely what you are looking for. Grab the relevant data from the selected row and then use intent.putExtra(key, value) to send it to the next activity.